# Localization of a finite type algebra is a localization of an integral domain of finite type

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $k$ be a field. Algebras are assumed to be commutative, associative, unital. If an integral domain over $k$ is a localization of a finitely generated $k$-algebra at a multiplicative set, is it also a localization of an integral domain that is of finite type over $k$ at a multiplicative set?

Comment: If your localized algebra $A$ is of the form $S^{-1}R$ where $R$ is a domain, then $A$ is also a domain. However it is possible to have localizations of finitely generated $k$-algebras which are not domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Indeed, suppose $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra and $S\subset A$ is a multiplicatively closed set such that the localization $A[S^{-1}]$ is a domain.  Let $I\subset A$ be the kernel of the localization map $A\to A[S^{-1}]$.  Then $I$ is finitely generated, and each element of $I$ is annihilated by some element of $S$.  We can thus choose a finitely generated multiplicatively closed subset $S_0\subseteq S$ such that every element of $I$ becomes $0$ in $A[S_0^{-1}]$.  This means that the localization map $A[S_0^{-1}]\to A[S^{-1}]$ is injective.  Thus $A[S_0^{-1}]$ is a domain which has $A[S^{-1}]$ as a localization, and it is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra.